# IDE для C и C++

Tags: c, ide, c++

Одной из проблем при программировании является выбор IDE, предлагаю в этом топике разобрать какие IDE существуют для C и C++. В чем преимущество одного над другим.

Comment: Дык это, а мы как будем делать — все ответы по мере поступления сгребать в один верхний, или лучше каждую среду разработки вынести в свой отдельный ответ?

Comment: /* и, таки, да, нам, всё же нужен какой-нибудь форум для координирования действий, поскольку местный формат плохо к этому располагает :( */

Comment: Вообще, не совсем понятен формат вики здесь. Мне кажется, что следовало бы запретить ответы в вики-вопросах, только комментарии. Тогда не было бы путаницы.

Comment: @kirelagin Пожелание учтено.

Comment: @cy6erGn0m Изначально предполагалось, что вики-вопрос будет без ответов. Но, к сожалению, у этого варианта оказался недостаток: такие вопросы будут при поиске показываются как не имеющие ответа. Поэтому ответ все же будет. Но мы можем сделать его единственным для вики-вопроса.

Comment: Возможно, стоит классифицировать такие "вопросы", как не подразумевающие ответа. Так что бы они были вне категорий отвеченные\неотевченные..

Comment: Вообще не вполне понятно, что за ерунда такая — викивопрос. Предлагаю переименовать это дело в Вики-статью. При конвертировании обычного вопроса в вики, он просто превращается в статью, состоящую из самого вопроса и нескольких ответов (ну, типа, ответ и подпись). Далее это добровольцами переделывается в нормальную статью. Ну или так и оставляется — тоже сойдёт.

Comment: А есть все таки удобные программисту среды вроде Visual Studio Express. В плане установил и пиши, а не ковыряйся в настройках и прикручивай компиляторы?

Comment: А куда делись пометки вики?

Comment: @Сергей Теперь вместо отметки вики, просто указывается автор - "Сообщество ХэшКод". Кроме того, для правки общего сообщения нужно 750 очков уважения.

Comment: К тому же NetBeans и Eclipse можно на линукс установить.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

### [Visual Studio Express](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/vs/express/)

Плюсы:

- Бесплатность
- Подстановка имени функции по началу
- Возможность свернуть блок

Минусы:

- Нельзя ресурсные файлы визуально редактировать
- Нет поддержки MFC/ATL
- Только Windows

### [Visual Studio Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/vs/community)

Плюсы:

- Бесплатность для определенных категорий пользователей (для разработчиков open-source или для небольших предприятий)
- Подстановка имени функции по началу
- Возможность свернуть блок
- Наличие редактора ресурсов, поддержка MFC/ATL

Минусы:

- Платный продукт для крупных предприятий (>250 ПК или > 1 млн. долларов годовой доход)
- Только Windows

### [Visual Studio (редакции Professional/Enterprise)](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/)

Плюсы:

- Подстановка имени функции по началу
- Возможность свернуть блок
- Наличие редактора ресурсов, поддержка MFC/ATL
- Поддержка TFS
- Расширенный функционал тестирования
- Наличие плагинов

Минусы:

- Платный продукт
- Только Windows

### [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/)

Плюсы:

- Рефакторинг
- Автоподстановка всего
- Кроссплатформенность
- Отладка через GDB

Минусы:
 - платный продукт

### [wxDev-CPP](http://wxdsgn.sourceforge.net/)

Плюсы:

- Бесплатность
- Наличие плагинов

Минусы:

- Отсутствие подстановки имени функции по началу

### [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/)

Плюсы:

- Бесплатность
- Плагины (невероятно много)
- Рефакторинг (не слишком крутой, правда)
- Автоподстановка любых идентификаторов
- Встроенная поддержка Doxygen
- Возможность отладки через GDB
- Кроссплатформенность

Минусы:

### [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)

Плюсы:

- Бесплатность
- Кроссплатформенность
- Поддержка множества компиляторов
- Поддержка пакетов от Dev-C++
- Еженедельные nightly build
- Множество шаблонов приложения для разных библиотек (wxWidjets, Ogre3D, Irrlicht, Opengl, SDL и т.д.)
- Поддержка Fortran 95 (иногда бывает очень полезно)

Минусы:

- Редкие официальные релизы
- Нет подсветки ошибок в редакторе
- Слабая аналитика
- Полное отсутствие рефакторинга

### [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/)

Плюсы:

- Бесплатность
- Плагины
- Рефакторинг
- Автоподстановки методов, классов и макросов
- Возможность отладки, включая удалённую
- Кроссплатформенность

Минусы:

- Недостаточная поддержка разных видов сборки
- Требует установки и подключения компиляторов

### [KDevelop](http://www.kdevelop.org/)

Плюсы:

- Бесплатный
- Автоподстановка кода (кое-где)
- Интересная подсветка кода
- Отладка через GDB

Минусы:

- Иногда недостаточно умный анализ кода

### [MinGW Developer Studio](http://koti.mbnet.fi/vaultec/mingwstudio.php)

Плюсы:

- Бесплатность

Минусы:

- TODO: указать минусы

### [CodeLite](http://codelite.org/)

Плюсы:

- Бесплатность

### [Qt Creator](https://www.qt.io/development-tools)

Плюсы:

- Бесплатность
- Кроссплатформенность
- Поддержка множества компиляторов
- Автоподстановка всего
- Возможность свернуть блок
- Рефакторинг
- Отладка через GDB/CDB
- Работа с git "из коробки"

### [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/)

Плюсы:

- Бесплатность

Минусы:

- Проект закрыт

### [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

Плюсы:

- бесплатный
- много плагинов
- настраиваемый
- работоспособное автодополнение
- работа с git "из коробки"
- работает также под linux/mac (для с++ нужно поставить плагин от Майкрософт - `Ctrl+P`, `ext install c++`)

Минусы:

- не умеет полноценно работать с кодом с++ под виндовс. Под linux/mac поддержка очень хорошая (включая отладчик)

Comment: vim/emacs не? При некоторой допилке -- вполне IDE.

Comment: Не. Всякие извращения не считаются :)

Comment: Не будете ли вы так любезны указать, какие из перечисленных IDE являются WYSIWYG..?...

Comment: из визуальных редакторов под виндовс только Visual Studio и Borland C++ Builder;
а под линя не знаю есть ли вообще

Comment: Есть ещё Qt Creator с QtDesigner

Comment: И, наверное, CodeLite, и не CodeLight.

Comment: а почему xCode забыли ?!

Comment: Лучше бы все варианты были отдельными ответами с отдельными голосами.

Comment: *не умеет полноценно работать с кодом с++ под виндовс. Под linux/mac поддержка очень хорошая (включая отладчик)*

Научите подключать библиотеки при использовании GCC под linux