# Среда разработки С++ для Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux

Добрый день, недавно установил себе новую Ubuntu(До этого пользовался Windows)
Возник вопрос какую среду разработки выбрать ?
Прошу сразу дать линк на скачивание.
Требования что бы среда соотвествовала всем стандартам С++(Собраный проект мог компилироватся в gcc);

Comment: sudo apt-get install vim

Comment: А какая именно это среда?

Comment: это один из крутейших редакторов.

Comment: Солидарен :)

Comment: Ну задавали же этот вопрос тут уже сто раз..

Answer (score 4):

Для начала рекомендую научиться компилировать в командной строке, изучить основные опции и флаги компилятора (gcc, естественно). А вот потом уже идти искать IDE, поскольку все равно как правило придется дополнительные опции прописывать вручную, а на простейших опциях далеко не уедешь. Потом, Вы не написали, какой Вас уровень владения языком.

Писать для начала лучше в блокнотах. Стандартный gedit - очень уважаю, для начала самое то. Еще лучше Kate. Vim, Emacs - очень мощные штуки, но с ними нужно долго и упорно разбираться.

Кроме того, очень рекомендуется разобраться с дополнительными средствами разработки: make, dbg, профилировщики и т.д. А тут командная строка - основное. Да и блокнотик.

Comment: Откровенно говоря мне больше нравится не gedit, а **medit** - это, во всех смыслах, мой любимый редактор после notepad++( но он под винду ) :)

Comment: Да? Надо будет попробовать

Comment: Попробуйте, редактор еще легче чем gedit + встроеная в редактор консоль, пальчики оближешь :)

Comment: Tapah leibh

Answer (score 4):

Вот тут ОЧЕНЬ подробно расписан ответ: [IDE для C и C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3592/). Остаётся только отсеять всё что про Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

NetBeans
Eclipse

И не среда соответствует стандартам, а код)

Comment: Дайте линк на скачивание пожалуйста.

Comment: netbeans.org
eclipse.org

Comment: Скачал Eclipse.

Comment: Тру пишут в **gedit**!!11!

Comment: gedit - нормальная вещь!

Comment: Стандартам соответствует компилятор. gcc соответствует? Соответствует!

Answer (score 3):

Я, например, использую CodeLite.
Отличная штука.

apt-cache search codelite

И установи все пакеты. Там их, кажется, 2 выползет.

Comment: Дайте линк на эту среду под Убунту

Comment: Какой линк? Это все ставится из репозиториев, одной строчкой в командной строке или с помощью Synaptic. Рекомендую для начала ознакомиться с работой в линуксе, она довольно сильно отличается от работы в винде.

Comment: в убунте (впрочем, как и в других линуксах), обычно не нужно идти на какие то сайты, вычивать инсталляторы и крякать потом. Для этого есть пакетный менеджер.
Что бы установить codelite, достаточно открыть консоль и написать `sudo apt-get install codelite` и нажать enter (потом нужно будет ввести свой пароль).

Answer (score 3):

Главное освойте (как следует) make.

Comment: И не только.

Comment: Остальное уже перечислили, а на одном из основных инструментов разработки внимания не заострили. 

А еще sh (bash) и многие команды Unix.

Comment: начнем с умения включать компьютер

Answer (score 0):

Один из самых популярных [Code Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)
Сам работаk на нем на Mac OSX/Windows/PC BSD