# IDE для C++

Tags: windows, ide, c++

Здравствуйте.

Уже несколько дней ищу себе IDE для программирования под C++. Пока нечего кроме как кучи  аргументов вернуться обратно на Visual Studio не нашел :). Хотелось бы хорошую IDE и не слишком навороченную и не "слабую". И поэтому решил спросить тут. Кто чем пользуется и почему?

Заранее спасибо и не пинайте пожалуйста :).

ps. Видел вот [эту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3592/ide-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-c-%D0%B8-c) тему. Но к примеру хорошо описанная и без единого минуса (!) там Eclipse мне не понравилась.

pps. Обратно на VS не вариант.

Comment: Из всех альтернативных `IDE`, которые я пробовал, более-менее можно пользоваться только `Qt Creator` и `KDevelop`.

Comment: КДевелоп под линукс =_=.

Comment: Чисто для интереса: а чем VS не устроила?

Comment: Не хочу разводить холивар =)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments#C.2FC.2B.2B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сложно сказать, что именно Вам нужно, т.к. всё зависит от Ваших задач. Например, для изучения языков Си/Си++, а также для написания программ на WinAPI или с использованем OpenGL подойдёт компилятор Dev-C++ - [оффсайт](http://www.bloodshed.net/) - (есть также wxDev-C++ - визуальная среда) или C-Free - [оффсайт](http://www.programarts.com/cfree_en/index.htm), - несмотря на то, что он так называется имеется 2 версии Standard и Pro (последняя платная). Я пока изучаю языки Си/Си++, поэтому, чаще всего пользуюсь Dev-C++, по той причине, что при написании кода на "чистом" Си, он позволяет объявлять переменные там, где это заблагорассудится (как в Си++), а не в начале блока, как во многих других средах. Если Вам нужна простенькая среда с дизайнером формы, то попробуйте [GcIDE](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Coding-languages-Compilers/GcIde.shtml) (оффсайта не нашёл). Эта среда имеет простой дизайнер формы, всего несколько компонентов (в основном визуальных), у которых всего несколько свойств и событий, т.е. ничего лишнего. Там, откуда Вы её скачаете, можно ещё много разных сред разработки найти. Я там эту среду нашёл случайно и решил попробовать.

Comment: Спасибо что так разжевали :).

Comment: GcIDE не скачивается и с софтпедии :(

Answer (score 2):

Как на счёт [NetBeans](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans)? Лично мне понравилась: быстрая, удобная, надёжная.

Comment: мне кажется вы погорячились насчет быстрая :)

Answer (score 1):

QtCreator 
Есть опрос на [опрос](http://habrahabr.ru/post/149773/) посмотрите комменты ну и сам опрос)))

Answer (score 1):

[Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) - зарекомендовавшая себя IDE для C/C++ и Фортрана 95. Детально настраиваемая подсветка синтаксиса, плагины, удобство - это всё про Code::Blocks. Плюсом ко всему Code::Blocks кроссплатформенный, вам не придётся создавать проекты для разных IDE на разных платформах, если проект open-source или у вас несколько компьютеров с разными операционками.

Comment: Пользуюсь. Но не могу не отметить кривую автоподстановку, которая с С работает нормально, а от шаблонов и новых фич С++ начинает слегка тупить.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте VIM

Comment: Совет глупый. Во-первых vim -- редактор, а не IDE. То, что реализуется плагинами к нему, до IDE не дотягивает. Во-вторых сам vim требует времени/желания на освоение (то, что силы, потраченные на освоение vim, окупаются, сейчас вспоминать не будем)

Comment: Vim - не IDE. Преодоление порога вхождения и установка несметного количества плагинов не стоит того. Тот же Code::Blocks всё имеет из коробки.

Answer (score 0):

Мне больше нравится QtCreator, порой еще использую NetBeans - тоже достаточно быстрая с удобной навигацией по коду и для рефакторинга годна.

Answer (score 0):

Code Blocks, вроде ничего лишнего, и вполне удобна, как по мне.
Очень легкая IDE, как уже сказал, ничего лишнего