# Какую программу надо установить чтобы изучать язык программирования  C++.

Tags: c++

Скажите пожалуйста, какую программу надо установить на компьютер , чтобы изучать язык программирования C++  ?

И есть бесплатные программы , и если есть то где их можно скачать?

И какой мощности нужен компьютер (подойтет ли нетбук)?

Comment: Самый минимум -- текстовый редактор + компилятор

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [IDE для C и C++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3592/ide-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-c-%d0%b8-c)

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите вот [эту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3592/178576) ветку, довольно хорошо разобраны плюсы и минусы того или иного IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю ОС Windows?
Если да, то для новичка я бы посоветовал [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) – бесплатная, простая в изучении IDE (там можно просто написать cpp файл и запустить его).
А вообще я рекомендую установить linux и программировать с помощью vim/g++. По моему мнению это идеал.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
А вот насчет компьютера, что можете посоветовать?
Буду очеть признателен.

Comment: Мощности надо немного, подойдет любой современный компьютер.

Comment: Идеала не существует. А связка vim/g++ неплохо работает и под Windows (см. cygwin или mingw/msys). (Некоторые заморочки только с help'ами, но, при наличии интернета это не проблема).

Comment: Можно и без cygwin и MSYS. Я под Windows использую MinGW gcc/g++ make, UnixUtils и Emacs.

Comment: Можно конечно, но это уже не то. Консоль в Windows очень уж страшная и неудобная. И менеджера пакетов нет. А в Linux: apt-get install g++ vim make и пошел программы писать.

Comment: @dzhioev Так @avp уже всё поставил. Нафига ему менеджер пакетов. А запускать компилятор/программу/gdb и из под Emacs никто не запрещает.

@avp Не хватает ещё одного слова: Viper

Comment: В Linux, да (можно еще svn добавить). Просто некоторые программки для линя, а другие для винды. В Linux я тоже Emacs предпочитаю (кстати, svn он понимает).  

Лучше вообще, когда программка работает и там и там.

Comment: @avp Опять не понял (как с точками). При чём тут Linux? Viper -- e-lisp-пакет, работает в любой операционке, а svn как-никак внешняя программа. О чём Вы?

Comment: @alexlz, видимо мы одновременно писали комментарии. 

Вашего (с Viper) я не видел, писал @dzhioev-у. 

svn без сомнения внешняя программа (хотя для начинающих бесполезная), просто написал про Emacs и svn и подчеркнул, что Emacs при редактировании файла понимает, что файл под управлением svn.

Comment: @alexlz Мы вообще-то не про @avp говорим, а про топикстартера. И не надо устраивать холивар Vim vs Emacs.

Comment: Какой холивар? Viper -- эмулятор vi под Emasc (один из). А Emacs'овский фронтенд к gdb -- вероятно лучший из существующих.

Comment: А причем тут вообще subversion? С каких пор для написания хелловорлдов понадобилась VCS? Visual Studio Express кстати бесплатна.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала тебе было бы не плохо вообще ознакомиться с компьютером и его внутренним устройством, почитать в википедии, как называются такие программы ( в которых пишут код ) и узнать, что это компиляторы. Рановато вам еще программировать, рановато, честно...

Answer (score 0):

У меня был нетбук Lenovo U160, можете в инете посмотреть характеристики, так вот я использовал Visual Studio 2010 и ничего не тормозила, компиляция проходила нормально, правда приложения писал консольные.

Answer (score -1):

Эм.. Язык обычно не программой изучают.

Если речь о выборе компилятора, то мне нравится Visual Studio. Имеет смысл брать самую новую. Версии Express и Community бесплатны. Professional доступен бесплатно для студентов по программе DreamSpark.

Да, нетбук подойдёт. У меня 2010я студия на нетбуке стояла - хорошо себе работала. Только учти, что у VS есть ограничения, связывающие версию VS с минимальной операционной системой.